# Trouble printing out a char * with variable args in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing my own printf for practice and am new to C.

For some reason, I'm not able to print out one of the args after I have cast it to a char *.

I'm getting a seg fault.

```
  void print_this(char* formatString, int numArgs, ... ) {
    if (formatString[0] != '%') {
            print_error(formatString);
    }


    // declare vars I guess since you can't define them in the case statement
    void * bsPtr;
    void * voidPtr;
    char * charPtr;

    int i = 0;

    // parse args
    va_list list;

    va_start(list, numArgs);

    switch (formatString[1]) { 
            case 'x':
                    charPtr = va_arg(list, char *);
                    printf("charPtr %s \n", charPtr); //segFault
                    break;
```

Comment: If the format is `%x` why are you printing `%s`?  What is the type of the actual argument?

Comment: This was just a test to see if I could parse the argument correctly.  The actual type will be  an int, but for this test I have tried to pass '10'.

Comment: You can't cast an int to a string.

Comment: Right, the arguments to this program are  print_this("%x", 1, '7')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments (which should actually be part of the question):

> the arguments to this program are print_this("%x", 1, '7')

You are calling it by passing a single character instead of a string.

It should be :

```
print_this("%x", 1, "7");
```

Comment: Welll, DERP...!